# HP Pavilion Gaming Desktop Ubuntu bootable USB not working

Tags: boot, grub2, 21.10

I've been trying to replace `Windows 10` with `Ubuntu 21.10`. But I've encountered so many problems. Basically, I followed a bunch of online tutorials and found out that I needed to create a bootable USB disk, which I did in every possible way with `Rufus` on my `Windows 10` device. Then disabled `Secure Boot`, which is the only option related to bootable medium issues listed in forums that I can disable/enable, and plugged in my USB stick, entered BIOS, changed the boot order, and selected `Ubuntu` from `Grub`, nothing that worked as it supposed to be after that. In forums and blogs, after people select the `Ubuntu` option, their Ubuntu just proceeds to installation steps but mine is stuck at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc9JO.jpg) screen. I hope I made myself clear, [here is the `BIOS` info of my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOTPJ.jpg).

Comment: did you use a USB3 or USB2 (slower)? Could you see any USB activity like a blinking led on the USB?  How long did you wait for the full boot (4-15 minutes not unusual)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to reinstall it on the USB using [Universal USB Installer – Boot from USB](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) program? it will make it Bootable , insert it after that then press f12 (in most devices) to choose first boot from USB.